# Display image in static folder Web2py

Tags: html, image, web2py

Hello everybody as it mention in the title in find difficulties to display my image on my html page

this is my code :

in my controller ( `default.py`)

```
import os
def serve_file():
    filename = request.args(0)
    path = os.path.join(request.folder, 'private', 'file_subfolder',filename)
    return response.stream(path)
```

in my views ( my file is in `/static/images` )

`<img src="{{=URL('static', 'images', args=image.jpg)}}" />`

Comment: Your `URL` call shows `args=image.img`, which would raise an exception. Is it actually `args='image.img'`? Also, are you sure the file is at `/static/images/image.jpg`? If so, your view code should work, though it will not call your `serve_file` action in `default.py`, as the URL points to the `/static` folder (which is where the image is).

Comment: i'm sure my file is at /static/images/image.jpg ,but  I don't think I understand the aim of the function I put in my controler .. My view still doesn't display the image ..

Comment: There is no aim to the function in your controller -- it simply is not used in this case. Its purpose would be to serve files out of your application's `/private` folder, in which case, the URL would be constructed as follows: `URL('default', 'serve_file', args='image.jpg')`.

Comment: If you are sure the file is in the `/static/images` folder of the application in which the view resides, then something else is going wrong. Could be a problem with your server configuration if it is handling static files directly, a problem with file permissions, etc. In the browser developer tools, check the network tab for the response when the browser requests the `/static/images/image.jpg` URL.

Comment: I will work on this, i find this too difficult when i know how it's easy to make it in html...Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish I found the solution to my problem

`{{=A(IMG(_src=URL('static/images', 'image.jpg'), _alt="comment"),_href=URL('default', 'index'))}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use:

`<img src="{{=URL('static', 'images')}}/image.jpg">`